# Apache secure folder to prevent malicious scripts on uploads

Tags: apache2

How can i set a folder in apache where my users can upload images and so on... but can not go out of this folder or execute any malicious script if the can hack my apache.

Is there something similar to a chroot for folders only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly configure directories/locations for script execution. Set AllowOverride none and don't configure the upload path as executable (CGI, mod_php, etc).

Scrub your config for anything configures handlers/types globally.